# Removal of Dojo Event Handlers

Tags: events, dojo

I'm not sure whether or not i need to remove any event handlers i've attached, or whether Dojo/JS will automagically clear my crap up after me...

Let's say i have two "Pages", both loaded via their own modules.  When Page 1 is loaded, i display 6 buttons all sharing an `on` event using the `on(element,event name,handler)` pattern. When i move to Page 2, the relevant Page 1 nodes are destroyed, new Page 2 nodes get loaded with different buttons and `on` handler(s).  Is there a requirement/benefit to ensuring that when i leave a "Page" that the event handlers created are all cleaned up behind me?

I've read this page, [Events with Dojo](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/events/index.html), from which i originally took away that `on` events follow the pattern: `on(element,event name,handler)`.

However, in considering this issue, i noticed the example:

```
var handle = on(myButton, "click", function(evt){
    // Remove this event using the handle
    handle.remove();
    ...
```

So, i guess, distilling the above, my questions are:

1. Do i need to worry about cleaning up subsequently inactive `on` events?
2. And if 1. == yes, is my only option to create references to the events?

Comment: This might be of help: [dijit/Destroyable](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Destroyable.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use `this.own()` from `dijit/Destroyable`

The `own()` function tracks specified handles and remove/destroy them when this instance is destroyed, unless they were already removed/destroyed manually.

More infos here:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Destroyable.html
`

Comment: Thanks, @GibboK (and @Himanshu).  I'll see if i can get my head around this and apply it to my code. What benefit is there from using Destroyable, instead of assigning a reference and then cleaning those up?

Comment: @FishBarFood  this.own() tracks instance an destroy them automatically, without you remove them manually. If you provide a code example on jsfiddle, I can try to have a look in more details :). If you think this answer also help you on solving this issue, please do not forget to approve it or upvote :) thanks!